# How can I filter a date of a DateTimeField in Django?

Tags: python, django, datetime, filter, django-queryset

I am trying to filter a `DateTimeField` comparing with a date. I mean:

```
MyObject.objects.filter(datetime_attr=datetime.date(2009,8,22))
```

I get an empty queryset list as an answer because (I think) I am not considering time, but I want "any time".

Is there an easy way in Django for doing this?

I have the time in the datetime setted, it is not `00:00`.

Comment: This is one of annoyances of Django. Considering this is a simple and common use case, there's no simple way to achieve this.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22085678/2859614

Answer (score 133):

Such lookups are implemented in `django.views.generic.date_based` as follows:

```
{'date_time_field__range': (datetime.datetime.combine(date, datetime.time.min),
                            datetime.datetime.combine(date, datetime.time.max))}
```

Because it is quite verbose there are plans to improve the syntax using `__date` operator. Check "[#9596 Comparing a DateTimeField to a date is too hard](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9596)" for more details.

Comment: Using with range:

`Q(created__gte=datetime.combine(created_value, time.min))`

Comment: Looks like it will land in Django 1.9: https://github.com/django/django/commit/44f3ee77166bd5c0e8a4604f2d96015268dce100#diff-5e313dd49d68a0a867d830a7f442d2a6R2471

Comment: New in Django 1.9: `Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__date=datetime.date(2005, 1, 1))`

Answer (score 120):

```
YourModel.objects.filter(datetime_published__year='2008', 
                         datetime_published__month='03', 
                         datetime_published__day='27')
```

// edit after comments

```
YourModel.objects.filter(datetime_published=datetime(2008, 03, 27))
```

doest not work because it creates a datetime object with time values set to 0, so the time in database doesn't match.

Comment: thx for the answer! the first alternative doesn't work with datetimefields. The second alternative works ;). If someone knows another method please answer

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects 
using datetime() from datetime module hrs,mins,secs is optional.

the second is from a working project with vars replaced, you can look in the docs it's correct

Comment: i know it is optional, the problem is that my datetimefield has the time setted, it is not 00:00

Comment: "the first alternative doesn't work with datetimefields." it'd be quite surprising, as datetime.datetime() returns a datetime object http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/0.96/models/basic/ check the model definition and examples: 
pub_date = models.DateTimeField() 
pub_date=datetime(2005, 7, 30)

Comment: "i know it is optional, the problem is that my datetimefield has the time setted, it is not 00:00" Oh, now i get it. Yes, with no time arguments it sets to 00, so it does not return :)

Comment: I'm using django 1.9 and python 2.7. This solution did not work for me.  I can filter on the year, but not the month or day. Thus `YourModel.objects.filter(datetime_published__year='2008')` is the only thing that worked. Bug in django 1.9?

Comment: Simple is better than complex =)

Answer (score 118):

Here are the results I got with ipython's timeit function:

```
from datetime import date
today = date.today()

timeit[Model.objects.filter(date_created__year=today.year, date_created__month=today.month, date_created__day=today.day)]
1000 loops, best of 3: 652 us per loop

timeit[Model.objects.filter(date_created__gte=today)]
1000 loops, best of 3: 631 us per loop

timeit[Model.objects.filter(date_created__startswith=today)]
1000 loops, best of 3: 541 us per loop

timeit[Model.objects.filter(date_created__contains=today)]
1000 loops, best of 3: 536 us per loop
```

**contains** seems to be faster.

Comment: This solution seems to be the most recent. I am surprised it got 4 upvotes, because when I try the `contains` solution, I get the error message: `Unable to get repr for <class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>`

Comment: I recheck and update the results today and I don't think your error it's caused by the `__contains` filter. But if you're running into issues you should try the [django docs example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter) which is using `__gte`.

Comment: The __contains method works fine for me.  I think this is probably the best answer since it provides performance comparisons.  I've voted more than one, but I'm surprised it doesn't have more upvotes.

Comment: I like this answer, but just a note of caution here: some of these options do not work optimally if the datetime field has been indexed. The `__gte` and `__range` filters play well with an indexed field (~0.008s for my case), but `__date`, `__contains` and `__startswith` do not (~1.6s for my case).

Answer (score 80):

Now Django has [__date](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#date) queryset filter to query datetime objects against dates in development version. Thus, it will be available in 1.9 soon.

Comment: Yup, it was added in 1.9 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#date

Comment: Best answer, valid for newer Django versions

Comment: This does not work for me, no idea why :(
I'm on django 1.11

My exact exception is: NotImplementedError: subclasses of basedatabaseoperations may require a datetime_cast_date() method

Comment: @AbdurRehmanKhan yes I am facing the same issue currently, using mongodb did you found any useful solution?

Answer (score 51):

```
Mymodel.objects.filter(date_time_field__contains=datetime.date(1986, 7, 28))
```

the above is what I've used. Not only does it work, it also has some inherent logical backing.

Comment: Much better than all of the other answers here, thanks!

Answer (score 48):

As of Django 1.9, the way to do this is by using [`__date`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#date) on a datetime object.

For example:
`MyObject.objects.filter(datetime_attr__date=datetime.date(2009,8,22))`

Comment: I read several answers stating about the '__date' , but I found all of them quite sophisticated, until I read your answer. It's simple and straight to the point.

Answer (score 27):

This produces the same results as using __year, __month, and __day and seems to work for me:

```
YourModel.objects.filter(your_datetime_field__startswith=datetime.date(2009,8,22))
```

Comment: looks like this one turns date object to string and do a string comparison of dates therefore forces db to do a full table scan. for big tables this one kill your performance

Answer (score 9):

You can do like this

```
MyObject.objects.filter(datetime_field__date=datetime.date(2009,8,22))
```

or if you want to filter between 2 dates

```
MyObject.objects.filter(
    datetime_field__date__range=(datetime.date(2009,8,22), datetime.date(2009,9,22))
)
```

Answer (score 8):

assuming active_on is a date object, increment it by 1 day then do  range

```
next_day = active_on + datetime.timedelta(1)
queryset = queryset.filter(date_created__range=(active_on, next_day) )
```

Answer (score 7):

You can filter by the Date as per as the date format is the same with your django date format. Default format is ISO YYYY-MM-DD

```
target_date = "2009-08-22"
qs = MyObject.objects.filter(datetime_attr__date=target_date)
```

Answer (score 4):

There's a fantastic blogpost that covers this here: [Comparing Dates and Datetimes in the Django ORM](http://blog.zdsmith.com/posts/comparing-dates-and-datetimes-in-the-django-orm.html)

The best solution posted for Django>1.7,<1.9 is to register a transform:

```py
from django.db import models

class MySQLDatetimeDate(models.Transform):
    """
    This implements a custom SQL lookup when using `__date` with datetimes.
    To enable filtering on datetimes that fall on a given date, import
    this transform and register it with the DateTimeField.
    """
    lookup_name = 'date'

    def as_sql(self, compiler, connection):
        lhs, params = compiler.compile(self.lhs)
        return 'DATE({})'.format(lhs), params

    @property
    def output_field(self):
        return models.DateField()
```

Then you can use it in your filters like this:

```
Foo.objects.filter(created_on__date=date)
```

**EDIT**

This solution is definitely back end dependent. From the article:

> Of course, this implementation relies on your particular flavor of SQL having a DATE() function. MySQL does. So does SQLite. On the other hand, I haven’t worked with PostgreSQL personally, but some googling leads me to believe that it does not have a DATE() function. So an implementation this simple seems like it will necessarily be somewhat backend-dependent.

Comment: is this MySQL specific? wondering about the class name choice.

Comment: @BinojDavid Yeah, it is backend dependent

Comment: I tested it using Django 1.8 and PostgreSQL 9.6.6 and it works perfectly. Actually using PostgreSQL you can also use this syntax: `return '{}::date'.format(lhs), params`

Answer (score 3):

```
MyObject.objects.filter(datetime_attr__date=datetime.date(2009,8,22))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an interesting technique-- I leveraged the startswith procedure as implemented with Django on MySQL to achieve the result of only looking up a datetime through only the date. Basically, when Django does the lookup in the database it has to do a string conversion for the DATETIME MySQL storage object, so you can filter on that, leaving out the timestamp portion of the date-- that way %LIKE% matches only the date object and you'll get every timestamp for the given date.

```
datetime_filter = datetime(2009, 8, 22) 
MyObject.objects.filter(datetime_attr__startswith=datetime_filter.date())
```

This will perform the following query:

```
SELECT (values) FROM myapp_my_object \ 
WHERE myapp_my_object.datetime_attr LIKE BINARY 2009-08-22%
```

The LIKE BINARY in this case will match everything for the date, no matter the timestamp. Including values like:

```
+---------------------+
| datetime_attr       |
+---------------------+
| 2009-08-22 11:05:08 |
+---------------------+
```

Hopefully this helps everyone until Django comes out with a solution!

Comment: Ok, so this does appear to be the same answer as mhost and kettlehell above, but with more description of what is happening in the backend. At least you have a reason to use contains or startswith along with the date() attribute of the datetime!

Answer (score 1):

See the article [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#gt)

```
ur_data_model.objects.filter(ur_date_field__gte=datetime(2009, 8, 22), ur_date_field__lt=datetime(2009, 8, 23))
```

Comment: in the django documentation it works because the datetimefiled  has time 00:00

Answer (score 0):

```
Model.objects.filter(datetime__year=2011, datetime__month=2, datetime__day=30)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm.. My solution is working:

```
Mymodel.objects.filter(date_time_field__startswith=datetime.datetime(1986, 7, 28))
```

Answer (score 0):

In Django 1.7.6 works:

```
MyObject.objects.filter(datetime_attr__startswith=datetime.date(2009,8,22))
```

Comment: This only works if you're looking for the exact date, you can't use `__lte` for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
person = Profile.objects.get(id=1)

tasks = Task.objects.filter(assigned_to=person, time_stamp__year=person.time_stamp.utcnow().year)
```

all my model do have time_stamp so I used the person objects to obtain the current year

Answer (score 0):

You can filter between some day ranges

`2016-01-01 00:00:00  <-->  2016-04-01 23:59:59.99999`

```
User.objects.filter(date_joined__gte=datetime.combine(datetime.strptime('2016- 
01-01', '%Y-%d-%m'), datetime.min.time()), 
date_joined__lte=datetime.combine(datetime.strptime('2016-04-01', '%Y-%d-%m'), 
datetime.max.time())).count()
```

`2016-01-01 00:00:00  <-->  2016-01-14 00:00:00`

```
User.objects.filter(date_joined__gte='2016-01-01', date_joined__lte='2016-1-14').count()
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation. you can use __date  with column name

```
Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__date=datetime.date(2005, 1, 1))
Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__date__gt=datetime.date(2005, 1, 1))
```

Answer (score -1):

Just as simple as that if you have a datetimefield your can use datetime.date.today()

```
context['now'] = Mymodel.objects.filter(date_time_field=datetime.date.today())
```