# Django model timerange filtering method

Tags: django, django-models, filtering, date-range

I saw the next two methods in an old question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317714/how-can-i-filter-a-date-of-a-datetimefield-in-django) but it is not clear for me what is the difference between:

```
{'date_time_field__range': (datetime.datetime.combine(date, datetime.time.min),
                        datetime.datetime.combine(date, datetime.time.max))}
```

and

```
YourModel.objects.filter(datetime_published__year='2008', 
                     datetime_published__month='03', 
                     datetime_published__day='27')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Was confused about this myself, but I think I've worked it out :-D I found [the documentation about the range lookup option](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#range) very helpful.

When you do:

```
YourModel.objects.filter(datetime_published__year='2008', 
                     datetime_published__month='03', 
                     datetime_published__day='27')
```

The SQL will look something like:

```
SELECT ... WHERE EXTRACT('year' FROM pub_date) = '2008'
             AND EXTRACT('month' FROM pub_date) = '03'
             AND EXTRACT('day' FROM pub_date) = '27';
```

Whereas this part of django's generic date based views:

```
{'date_time_field__range': (datetime.datetime.combine(date, datetime.time.min),
                        datetime.datetime.combine(date, datetime.time.max))}
```

becomes something like:

```
YourModel.objects.filter(datetime_published__range=(
                datetime.datetime.combine('2008-03-27',datetime.time.min),
                datetime.datetime.combine('2008-03-27',datetime.time.max)
                                                                  )
```

which produces SQL along the lines of:

```
SELECT ... WHERE datetime_published BETWEEN '2008-03-27 00:00:00'
                                        AND '2008-03-27 23:59:59';
```

(the format of the timestamp in the last SQL example is wrong obviously, but you get the idea)

Hope that answers your question :)

Comment: I expect the last SQL to be much faster on most databases since it can be optimized, so using the `range` lookup is probably the preferred way, even if you have to use a "bogus" start date.