# How Use Django ORM to query only by time in a datetimefield

Tags: python, django

I have a datetimefield: 2013-03-14 17:30:21
I want to query ONLY by the time, ignoring the date.

Like this:

> list = MyModel.filter(dateTimeField_*time*_gte = '09:00:00', dateTimeField_*time*_lte = '10:00:00')

but it doesn't work.

Comment: I need to filter only by time, ignoring the date.

Comment: Have you found any solution on that?

Answer (score 0):

See this Stack Overflow question for some insights on how to filter by a date or time range: [Django model timerange filtering method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043859/django-model-timerange-filtering-method)

Comment: I need to filter only time, ignoring date

Comment: This question explain how to query by date, by date and time, but not for time ONLY