# DateTimeField without time

Tags: django

```
class Data(models.Model):
    time = models.DateTimeField()
```

I have in my variable:

```
var = 2013-01-17 17:30

Data.objects.filter(time=var)
```

I need all Data from this day(2013-01-17 - without time)

How to do?

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem and fixed it simply by using `models.DateField()` instead of `models.DateTimeField()`.

Comment: This should be the excepted answer

Comment: Really exceptional. +2

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be a very straightforward way of doing this. See [How can I filter a date of a DateTimeField in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317714/how-can-i-filter-a-date-of-a-datetimefield-in-django) .

You can use strptime to get a datetime out of your string ( [Converting string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime) ):

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime.strptime(var, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use range inside the filter

```
Data.objects.filter(date__range=(date_min, date_max))
```

you can set the time between 00.00  and 23.59