# Filtering models using date range

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I am using django_filter along with django_rest_framework to create rest end-points for my data.

I have a model which I would like to filter by passing start_date and end_date as query parameters. So far, I have found that   `DateFilter` and `DateRangeFilter` classes in `django_filters` module. But I could not find any documentation related to them.

Here is the code for the model, serializer and the view.

```
class Holiday(models.Model):

holiday_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
city_name    = models.ForeignKey(City)
description  = models.CharField(max_length=100)
date         = models.DateTimeField()

def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s %s' %(self.holiday_name, self.city_name)

class HolidaySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Holiday
    fields = ('holiday_name', 'city_name','description', 'date')


class HolidayFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
  class Meta:
     model = Holiday
     start_date = django_filters.DateFilter(name="date",    lookup_type='gte')
    end_date   = django_filters.DateFilter(name="date", lookup_type='lte')
    fields = ['date']


class HolidayList(generics.ListAPIView):
  queryset = Holiday.objects.all()
  serializer_class= HolidaySerializer
  filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
  filter_class = HolidayFilter
```

I can pass start_date and end_date as parameters, but it is not working. I get the entire queryset.

Comment: Please add some code for serializers, models and views.

Comment: there is an other question here on so that could help you: [How to use django_filters.DateFilter][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21743271/how-to-use-django-filters-datefilter

Comment: I updated the question with code. Still not sure what I am missing.