# how to compare only date from a model's datetimefield with current date?

Tags: python, linux, django, web, frameworks

I want to use `Model.objects.filter(datetime_lte=datetime.datetime.now.date())`
How exactly can I achieve this? I am using django 1.6.5. I want only records of current date. This will give all previous day's records also

Comment: What is the problem with this code?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Django filter datetime base on date only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22085398/django-filter-datetime-base-on-date-only)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`__range`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#range) field lookup:

```
start = datetime.date.today()
end = start + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
Model.objects.filter(datetime__range=(start, end))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

Model.objects.filter(created_at__date=today)

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
Model.objects.filter(created_at__year = timezone.now().year,
                    created_at__month=timezone.now().month,
                    created_at__day=timezone.now().day)
```