# Unable to filter datetime field on live server

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Hi i am take a record of employe punch in time and punch out time. I Want to filter queryset according to current date
Everythings work fine on my local server but it doesn't work on my live server.

my Model code is below:-

```
class EmpAttendenceSheet(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=100,verbose_name='user')
    Employee = models.ForeignKey(EmployeeRegistration,on_delete=models.CASCADE,max_length=150,verbose_name='Employee Name')
    intime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True)
    instate = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    outtime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True)
    outstate = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    approve = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,auto_created=True)
```

my Live server queries are as below:-

```
>>> from attendance.models import EmpAttendenceSheet
>>> from django.utils import timezone
>>> today = timezone.localtime(timezone.now())
>>> today = timezone.localtime(timezone.now())
>>> attendance = EmpAttendenceSheet.objects.filter(intime__day=today.day,intime__month=today.month,intime__year=today.year)
>>> attendance
<QuerySet []>
```

I set the timezone in setting.py as TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'

Comment: `EmpAttendenceSheet.objects.filter(intime=datetime.today())` ?

Comment: I think this will match will current date and time also and time can very with every second. so this query will not work. i want to filter according to only date

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django filter datetime base on date only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22085398/django-filter-datetime-base-on-date-only)

Comment: @boomyourcareer you can use `__in` filter where you define range of date ie today and next day. , one way is that also