# django queryset filter datetimefield

Tags: python, django, filter, django-queryset

I am strungling to use the django queryset API reference with filters based on the DateTimeField.

I have prepared the following model, in my models.py:

```
class KleedkamerIndeling(models.Model):

gametimedate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)    # date and time of game
hometeam = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)                     # name of home playing team  team
homedressroom = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)                # dressing room of home playing team
awayteam = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)                     # name of visiting team team
awaydressroom = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)                # dressing room of visiting team team
pitch = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)                        # name / number of playing pitch
referee = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)                      # name of referee
refdressroom = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)                 # name/number of referee dressroom
timestamp = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
indelings_datum = models.DateField() # need to change to datum added later

def __unicode__(self):
    return smart_unicode(self.hometeam)
```

I want to access the database based on the present date. Should be something like:

```
queryset = KleedkamerIndeling.objects.all().filter(gametimedate=date.today())
```

This worked before when I used a 'datefield' but I decided to go to a datetimefield because I also need the starting time of the game played.

I have seached the web and stackoverflow and found the following older topic, [How can I filter a date of a DateTimeField in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317714/how-can-i-filter-a-date-of-a-datetimefield-in-django) but I stungle on the implemenation.

I want to create a queryset that obtains all the 'KleedkamerIndeling' that are available for today's date. Subsequently I want to check if there are more then 10 objects in the list. If that's the case than I want to further narrow it down based on the current time, also via a filter on the datetimefield. Lastly I want to sort the object list such that it is sorted on time.

I know that my problem has to do which the caracteristics of the datetimefield van I appreciate a couple lines of code to help me move foreward. I have been trying to find the right query in the python manage.py shell all afternoon....

My model most work because the queryset = KleedkamerIndeling.objects.all() seems to work and I am able to set up seperate list for each object called 'game0 through game10 from the queryset list.

I have a further issue on the datetimefield format:

I have defined a 'KleedkamerIndeling' that describes a game that starts at 13:00. I have used the objects in the queryset list to define 10 different 'game'objects. i.e. game0 = [queryset[0].hometeam etc... though game10 if applicable. The gametime field is displayed in the template via a filter like: {{game0.0|date:"H"}}:{{game0.0|date:"i"}}. I still end up with the ':' in the case of no game0 object. I plan to solve this via a if else script in the template or in the view, or is there a better way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using a datetime field you want to make your query’s using datetime objects. so first order the queryset from earliest to latest then filter out the events tat arn't occurring today.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, time

today = datetime.now().date()
tomorrow = today + timedelta(1)
today_start = datetime.combine(today, time())
today_end = datetime.combine(tomorrow, time())

queryset = KleedkamerIndeling.objects.order_by('-gametimedate').filter(gametimedate__gte=today_start).filter(gametimedate__lt=today_end)
```

After that we can check if there are more then 10 objects, filter by the current time, and limit the queryset to 10 objects.

```
if queryset.count() > 10:
  queryset = KleedkamerIndeling.objects.filter(gametimedate__gte=datetime.now())[:10]
```

Comment: Great, this seems to work. Thanks! Did receive and Runtimewarming while trying this in the python shell. It states 'RuntimeWarning: DateTimeFiled KleedkamerIndeling.gametimedate received a naive datetime (2014-12-06 00:00:00) while time zone support is active'. But apart from this it works!

Comment: Timezones can be tricky I would recommend reading through some of djangos documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/timezones/#naive-and-aware-datetime-objects