# How to filter objects on datetime fields?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have the following model:

```
class Announcement(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_start = models.DateTimeField()
    date_end = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I can filter the objects on `is_active` field like:

```
def announcements(request):
    announcements = Announcement.objects.all().filter(
        is_active = True
    )
    return HttpResponse(
        serializers.serialize("json", announcements))
```

This works fine. But when I want to filter them based on `date_start` field like this:

```
def announcements(request):
    announcements = Announcement.objects.all().filter(
        date_start >= datetime.now()
    )
    return HttpResponse(
        serializers.serialize("json", announcements))
```

I am getting `global name 'date_start' is not defined` error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I filter a date of a DateTimeField in Django?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317714/how-can-i-filter-a-date-of-a-datetimefield-in-django)

Comment: You do not need to call .all() before using filter(), as filter() is proxied to the queryset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/) filter lookups, [__gte (greater than or equal)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#gte):

```
announcements = Announcement.objects.all().filter(date_start__gte = datetime.now())
```

Answer (score 3):

This syntax is wrong:

```
announcements = Announcement.objects.all().filter(date_start >= datetime.now())
```

`filter` requires Python keyword arguments. So in effect you could:

```
announcements = Announcement.objects.all().filter(date_start__gte=datetime.now())
```

More on that on [Django docs: Making queries: Field lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/).