# Django: datetime filter by date ignoring time

Tags: python, django

I am trying to filter `Match`es scheduled in a certain day. I can't just do this:

```
match_queryset.filter(start=date)
```

because it also filters by time, but I can do this:

```
match_queryset.filter(start__year=a_date.year, start__month=a_date.month, start__day=a_date.day)
```

But this is too complex, I feel like there could be a simpler way.

Then I can also use a range:

```
t0 = datetime.datetime.combine(a_date, datetime.time(0, 0))
t1 = datetime.datetime.combine(a_date, datetime.time(23, 59, 59))
match_queryset.filter(start__gte=t0, start__lte=t1)
```

But this just seems to be an overkill and it probably generates an inefficient query.

Can't I just make a query to target the actual date? Something like:

```
# this of course doesn't work
match_queryset.filter(start__date=date)
```

No need to say I have tried looking for solution and could not find any.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1973917/2689986

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil that's literally my second solution

Comment: I mentioned it for this quote : Because it is quite verbose there are plans to improve the syntax using `__date` operator. Check "[#9596 Comparing a DateTimeField to a date is too hard](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9596)" for more details.

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil that was from 2009, they haven't implemented `__date` yet?

Comment: Why not just add a `DateField`?

Comment: @dabadaba [New in Django 1.9](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#date)

Comment: @Jkdc yeah why not just change the entire requirements and thousands of entries in production?...

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil ah cool, good to know, a shame I'm stuck with a lower version though

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From Django 1.9 you can use the [`__date` field lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#date), exactly as you have mentioned in your question. For older versions, you will have to do with the other methods.

e.g.

```
Entry.objects.filter(start__date=datetime.date(2005, 1, 1))
Entry.objects.filter(start__date__gt=datetime.date(2005, 1, 1))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can't use the `__date` filter, I think the cleanest way would be to do this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

d = datetime.now()  # or whatever you want

match_queryset.filter(start__gte=d.date(), start__lt=d.date()+timedelta(days=1))
```

If you have `USE_TZ=True` in Django's `settings.py`, you will get warnings:

```
RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField (...) received a naive datetime (...) while time zone support is active.
```

but the filter will still work. The comparison will be made in Django's timezone (`TIME_ZONE` from `settings.py`), at least that's what I'm getting.