# Django filter by date

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have

```
Class Profile(models.Model)
    turn_off_date = models.DateTimeField(null= True, blank = True,auto_now = False)
```

I need to find all profile records, that have expiration date= *Exactly* x days from now.
How do I do this?
I can think of iterating through all profiles and manually comparing dates, but it seems not effective

Update:

I neeed to filter by date, not by datetime field as in duplicate question

Right now I am doing it like this:

```
profiles = Profile.objects.all()
for profile in profiles:
        if(profile.days_left() == x):
           print(profile.days_left())
```

And in my Profile model I defined a method:

```
def days_left(self):
        turn_off_date = self.turn_off_date

        days_left = (turn_off_date - datetime.now()).days
        if days_left < 0:
            days_left = 0
        return days_left
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django filter older than day(s)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984047/django-filter-older-than-days)

Comment: You may need to check this [filter by date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668619/django-database-query-how-to-filter-objects-by-date-range)

Comment: Not an exact duplicate but your question is ambiguous. What do you mean by `expiration date= x days from now`? Exactly that date or before/after?

Comment: @Selcuk exactly

Comment: What do you you mean by filter by `date` not `datetime`? What have you tried?

Comment: @Sayse see upd2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just query by [`__date`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#date) with a given date

> For datetime fields, casts the value as date. Allows chaining additional field lookups. Takes a date value.

```
.filter(turn_off_date__date=(datetime.now()+timedelta(days=x)).date())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [range](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#range) to achieve this,

Example:

```
Profile.objects.filter(turn_off_date__range=(start_date, end_date))
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess something like this will work fine:

> From Django 1.9 you can use the `__date` field lookup, exactly as you
>   have mentioned  in your question. For older versions, you will have to
>   do with the other methods.

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/45735324/2950593