# Query with just the date

Tags: python, django

```
In [97]: cust = CustomerProfile.objects.get(pk=100)

In [98]: CustomerProfile.objects.filter(user__date_joined=datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 28))
Out[98]: <QuerySet []>

In [99]: CustomerProfile.objects.filter(user__date_joined=datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 28, 14, 43, 51, 925548))
Out[99]: <QuerySet [<CustomerProfile: George George's customer profile>]>
In [100]: cust
Out[100]: <CustomerProfile: George George's customer profile>
In [101]: cust.user.date_joined
Out[101]: datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 28, 14, 43, 51, 925548)
```

I am not sure why it is not working here just with the date 2017/07/28. Why is it empty with just the date? How could I obtain the last queryset with just the date and not all the stuff `datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 28, 14, 43, 51, 925548)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `__date` from [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#date), or look on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317714/how-can-i-filter-a-date-of-a-datetimefield-in-django) - there are a lot of good solution.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are facing this problem is because you are trying to search for a specific datetime. This means, you are looking for a combination of date *and* time. So, when you create the `datetime.datetime` object, `datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 28)`, you are basically created a date with a time of 0 hours, 0 minutes and 0 seconds.

In order to filter just by the date only, you can use the `__date` attribute to compare the date *only*.

So, your comparison would look like:

```
CustomerProfile.objects.filter(user__date_joined__date=datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 28))
```