# Django DateTimeField date filter not working

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a `DateTimeField` named `created_at` in my model. I Would like to query the objects which are created today. From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317714/how-can-i-filter-a-date-of-a-datetimefield-in-django) I have used the following query set,

```
In [70]: today = datetime.datetime.today().date()
In [72]: Business.objects.filter(created_at__date=today)
Out[72]: <QuerySet []>
```

It returns zero results. I have make sure that there is an entry in the database, which was created today. I know that I can also use

```
Business.objects.filter(created_at__contains=today)
```

But it yields results with a warning:

```
django/db/backends/mysql/base.py:71: Warning: (1292, "Incorrect datetime value: '%2017-12-21%' for column 'created_at' at row 1")
```

I'm using MySQL database. My Model is

```
class Business(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
    category = models.CharField(max_length=120)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Business'
        unique_together = (('name', 'url'),)
```

Comment: `today = datetime.datetime.today()` try this

Comment: @MD.KhairulBasar: Still no results.

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36462961/3968623)

Comment: post the created_at column data from the database

Comment: @Exprator: It's 2017-05-11 04:52:25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.utils import timezone
Business.objects.filter(created_at__gte=timezone.now())
```

i guess this will be better for you.

and change your model

```
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

then makemigrations, migrate and then add some data and try again

Comment: It shows a warning `RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Business.created_at received a naive datetime (2017-12-21 05:28:17.113688) while time zone support is active.` but there are no results.

Comment: do you have any data of today?? 21-12-2017 and try the edited ans once

Comment: Still not getting. I have an object created today. `b = Business.objects.get(id=4)`. `b.created_at` prints `datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 21, 9, 53, 31, tzinfo=<UTC>)`

Comment: Edited. The models has generated by using `inspectdb` command.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161678/discussion-between-arun-and-exprator).

Comment: Sure, with pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

Use timezone library

```
today = timezone.datetime.today().date()
```

else

```
today = timezone.now().date()
```

Comment: It's not working.Even `Business.objects.filter(created_at__date=datetime.date(2017, 12, 21))` does not yield results.

Comment: Try to print the result in console first and checkout the data in "today"

Comment: check the data type. In case of any miss match you wont get the desired result

Comment: `today` is `datetime.date(2017, 12, 21)` and the DateTimeField in object is `datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 21, 9, 53, 31, tzinfo=<UTC>)`