# Django __date not working with date() or string

Tags: django, datetime

I have the following model field:

```
inbound_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

I want to filter on date, and not care about the time.
I have inserted two test objects which return the following values for inbound_date:

```
2018-11-14 00:00:00+00:00
2018-11-15 08:37:09+00:00
```

But all my attempts at retrieving the objects fail:

```
AppInbound.objects.filter(inbound_date__date=datetime.date(2018, 11, 15))
```

Or

```
AppInbound.objects.filter(inbound_date__date='2018-11-15')
```

But all seem to return an empty QuerySet.
The only one I did manage to get working was:

```
AppInbound.objects.filter(inbound_date__startswith='2018-11-15')
```

Which returns the the last objects, with datetime of 2018-11-15 08:37:09+00:00.

Can someone explain what is going wrong here?

It is an MySQL database, and we have TZ enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
 AppInbound.objects.filter(inbound_date__lt=datetime.date(2018, 11, 15), inbound_date__gte=datetime.date(2018, 11, 14))  # will return objects for 14th November.
```

Or you can check [this answer on how to filter on specific dates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1317725/2696165).

If you are only concerned with using date then [DateField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField) should be used here:

```
inbound_date = models.DateField()
```

Then you should be able to filter with date object(`datetime.date`).

Comment: Changing the field to DateField is no option, I am not the only user of this db, I just happen to only need the date. According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#date) you should be able to do `Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__date=datetime.date(2005, 1, 1))` which is a lot easier than 2 filters, lt and gte.

Comment: You are right. I was able to work it in Postgresql. Maybe its an issue with timezone, because as per docs, *fields are converted to the current time zone before filtering*. Still, you can try with `(inbound_date__year='2018', inbound_date__month='11', inbound_date__day='15')`

Comment: Does not work either. I have both a PostgreSQL db and a MySQL db connected, the PostgreSQL db works fine, MySQL not. It probably has something to do with the TZ. Thanks anyway.