# Get all objects with today date, django

Tags: python, django, web

I have a model like this

```
class Maca(models.Model):
   created_at = models.DateTimeField(
     auto_now_add=True
   )
```

Now I want in the views.py file to get all the entries that have created today,

I'm trying this

```
Maca.objects.filter(created_at=datetime.today().date())
```

But this looks for the clock that object is created too.

P.S I can't change the field in model because I need the clock too in other purposes.

Can someone help me to select all entries that have been created today?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*You have to just write a valid filter like this :*

```
from datetime import datetime

today = datetime.today()

year = today.year
month = today.month
day = today.day

meca = Meca.objects.filter(created_at__year=year, 
created_at__month=month, created_at__day=day)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the main reason is because you trying to compare `dt` field with `date`.

You can [use prefixes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317714/how-can-i-filter-a-date-of-a-datetimefield-in-django) for a field.

Or you can compare your 'today' value as `dt`(just an example):

```
today = datetime.today().replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
records = Maca.objects.filter(created_at >= today)
```

Answer (score 1):

there many ways to get today data from database.

```
year =  datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%y')
month =  datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%m')
day =  datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d')
filtereddata = Maca.objects.filter(created_at__year=year,created_at__month=month, created_at__day=day )
```

the second way is to filter with contains

```
filtereddata = Maca.objects.filter(created_at__contains=datetime.today().date())
```

if datetime.datetime not work. just remove one datetime only use single datetime

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `__date` like this.

```
Maca.objects.filter(created_at__date=datetime.today().date())
```